# regex pattern to highlight all the matches for the punctuation in VBA

Tags: regex, vba

need an expression to allow only the below pattern

> end word(dot)(space)start word [eg: end. start]

in other words

> no space before colon,semicolon and dot |
>   one space after colon,semicolon and dot

rest of the all other patterns need to get capture to identify such as

> end.start   || end . start || end .start

i used

> "([\s{0,}][\.]|[\.][\s{2,}a-z]|[\.][\s{0,}a-z])"

but not working as i expected.Need your support please
[need_regex_patterns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YAh8.png)    [aim_of_regex_need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0Tmh.png)

Comment: Do you mean like this? `\w+ ?[.;:] ?\w+` https://regex101.com/r/BPhMeS/1 and `\w+\. ?\w+` https://regex101.com/r/MlGkKO/1

Comment: No. it is getting highlighted all the ./;/:  eg: end;start || end ; start || end ;start ||end. start       . Need to omit select the last pattern which is being right

Comment: So it should only match the last one? `\w+[.;:] \w+` https://regex101.com/r/P14jcv/1

Comment: \w+\. ?\w+    .it is working as vice versa. selecting only the last pair which is being right. But the need is to select rest of the all pairs which is not correct

Comment: It could be like this `\w+ ?[;:] ?\w+` Then the spaces are optional and the dot will not be matched. https://regex101.com/r/GK2T1r/1

Comment: ULTIMATE. thanks a lot and saved me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could match 1+ word characters using `\w+` and match either a colon or semi colon using a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[;:]` between optional spaces  `?`.

After that, match again 1+ word characters.

```
\w+ ?[;:] ?\w+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GK2T1r/1)

To match the dot followed by a single space variant, you don't need a character class but you could match the dot only using `\.`

```
\w+\. \w+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/n1MBGz/1)

**Edit**

To highlight all the matches for the punctuations:

```
(?: [.:;]|[.:;] {2,}|(?<=\S)[;:.](?=\S))
```

*Explanation*

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[.:;]` match a space followed by either `.` `:` or `;`
  - `|` Or
  - `[.:;] {2,}` Match one of the listed followed by 2 or more spaces
  - `|` Or
  - `(?<=\S)[;:.](?=\S)` Match one of the listed surrounded by non whitespace chars
- `)` Close group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vAjMku/1)

Comment: If you edit the question, there is a pictogram where you can add an image.

Comment: Not sure if the lookahead is supported, but you could try `(?: [.:]|\. {2,}|;(?=\S))` https://regex101.com/r/SqGn0Q/1 Else you could match the semicolon part `(?: [.:]|\. {2,}|\w;\w)` See https://regex101.com/r/VY2m6m/1

Comment: You could take that part of of the alternation `(?: [.:;]|\. {2,}|(?<=\S)[;:.](?=\S))`  https://regex101.com/r/YQOPty/1

Comment: YES "(?: [.:;]|\. {2,}|(?<=\S)[;:.](?=\S))" worked as charm. Sincere thanks. is it possible to separate this pattern for each punctuation? if too complex to do please advise me

Comment: You could take all 3 patterns out of the alternation. See https://regex101.com/r/K09SOx/1 and https://regex101.com/r/MMjU9W/1 and https://regex101.com/r/XgNRn0/1

Comment: "(?: +[.]|(?<=[.]) {2,}|(?<=\S)[.](?=\S))" is selecting numbers also. need to exclude numbers like 12.50

Comment: Then you can exclude matching digits. https://regex101.com/r/FWjeMU/1 Shall we clean up some of our comments above as it becomes a long list. Note that the more edge case you have, the longer the pattern will be.

Comment: +[.:;] is working but +(?<=[.:;]) not working to omit the punctuation for the selection. is it possible or not?

Comment: also the pattern we used (?<=[.:;]) to eliminate the punctuation throws error in VBA